# why doesn't my image drawing work javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

what happens is that the image is drawn on the canvas but its always the same size no matter how big i make the image the drawn won is always 300 by 168 for some reason its also always off center. please and thank you for your help and attention.

```
function update_image(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'fractal.png';
    var canvas = document.getElementById('display');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.style.left = window.screen.width / 2 - (img.width / 2) + "px";
        canvas.style.top = window.screen.height / 3 - (img.height / 2) + "px";
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
                
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, img.width, img.height);
                
        imageData.data = editPixels(imageData.data, [img.width, img.height]);
                
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: could you go into a little bit more detail than just a link

Comment: A canvas doesn't adapt the size of the image you're drawing to it. You've either to scale the image when drawing, or resize the canvas according to the dimensions of the image to draw to the canvas. Resizing must not be made with CSS, use canvas.width and canvas.height properties instead.

Comment: oh my god your amazing thank you so much!